# Can't get the route file to wait for all the api calls to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I've tried standard JS timers, I attempted to make an async function, I tried having a counter and if statement, but nothing is working for me; there's technically like 21 api calls being done here, and I need my program to work. My calls work in the console logs, but it wants to send the data back to the page before movieData is filled. As it sits right now, it just pushes an empty array to the page.

I've been all over the web and this site, to no avail.

```js
const router = require("express").Router()
const axios = require('axios')
require("dotenv").config()
// const controller = require("../controllers/userController")

function movieSearch(req, res) {
    const tmdbApiKey = process.env.tmdbApiKey
    let searchQuery = req.params.search
    
    const url = `https://tastedive.com/api/similar?type=movies&q=${searchQuery}`

    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            let recommendations = response.data.Similar.Results

            console.log("Recommendations: ", recommendations)

            let movieData = []

            for (let i = 0; i < recommendations.length; i++) {
                const singleUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${tmdbApiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&query=${recommendations[i].Name}`
                axios.get(singleUrl)
                    .then(singleResponse => {
                        let single = singleResponse.data.results
                        
                        for (let x = 0; x < single.length; x++) {

                            if (single[x].title.toLowerCase() === recommendations[i].Name.toLowerCase()) {
                                console.log("Single[i]: ", single[x])
                                movieData.push(single[x])
                                break
                            }

                        }
                        
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })

            }

            res.send(movieData) // I still have to find someway to tell it to wait to send the data

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    
}

function showSearch(req, res) {
    let searchQuery = req.params.search
    
    const url = `https://tastedive.com/api/similar?type=shows&q=${searchQuery}`

    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            let recommendations = response.data.Similar.Results
            res.send(recommendations)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    
}

router.get("/api/movie/:search", movieSearch)

router.get("/api/tv/:search", showSearch)

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Promise.all()`.

```
function movieSearch(req, res) {
//
//
let movieData = []
const promiseArr = []
           for (let i = 0; i < recommendations.length; i++) {
                const singleUrl = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${tmdbApiKey}&language=en-US&page=1&query=${recommendations[i].Name}`

                promiseArr.push(axios.get(singleUrl))
}// for loop
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(result => {});// Array of result of each API request
// Do further operation here
}
```

Problem with `Promise.all()` is process will fail with no result if any of the request failed. You can try [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: I had to refactor a ton of the code inside the promise all and add a 3rd for loop because it couldn't find recommendations[I], but I finally got it sending the data to the page. Thanks so much!